# Design flaw -- Trying to prevent cross-imports

Tags: python, import

The actual problem I'm facing is a lot more complex then this, but this is pretty much what it boils down to:

World.py

```
import Cell

worldobjects = []

for i in range(10): #create  a bunch of initial cells
    worldobjects.append(Cell.Cell())

while True:
    for obj in worldobjects:
        obj.update()
```

Cell.py

```
from World import worldobjects #This is the problem, python does not like cross imports

class Cell:
    def __init__(self):
        self.lifetime = 0 #Keep track of frames spent 'alive'

    def update(self):
        self.lifetime += 1 
        if self.lifetime > 30:
            worldobjects.append(Cell()) #Add a new cell to the world
            self.lifetime = 0 #Reset lifetime
```

The error which is a little non-specific, but I know it means I shouldn't be cross-importing stuff:

```
ImportError: No module named worldobjects
```

I know this is a design flaw but I'm not quite sure how I could work this out differently. As you can see from the code every cell is supposed to 'reproduce' every 30 frames, and the only way this is possible is by adding them to the array in the `World.py` file. I've considered moving the `worldobjects` array to its own file but that feels a bit dirty to me. Anyone that could assist me with this problem?

Comment: Thank you! I forgot about that and just as I was fixing it Kara corrected it for me :-)

Comment: My general understanding is that it is poor form to have anything outside of a class or function if you plan on importing some code.  Place the code that creates ```worldobjects``` into a function, then call that function in Cell.py

Comment: @wnnmaw I understand that it's poor form, but it has given me the least headache while working with Python and its (in my opinion) confusing importing system. As for your solution, I'm going to assume I still will have to import the creator function from World.py, which leaves me with the same problem I have now. Or did I misinterpret your answer?

Comment: Note that the error message in your question does **not** seem related to a cyclic import. It seems like the `import` is failing because it cannot find the right module. Running the scripts you have provided does **not** give the error you reported. You should really **always** copy the **whole** traceback you get, not just the last line which half of the time isn't so useful.

Comment: @Flubber, its not an answer, only a suggestion to make your life easier. It likely won't impact your problem, but it should make your life easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good example of why global variables are a bad idea. Instead of Cells needing to know about the existence of a global called worldobjects, it would be better to tell each cell about this variable when it's created. You could pass a reference to it in the constructor, for example. Or create a new function that encapsulates both the creation of a new cell and telling it about the world objects.

Or, you could move the lifetime-checking logic out of the cell entirely, and put that in the world update. That actually makes more sense to me, since I wouldn't have each cell responsible for creating new cells.

Comment: I'm just going to roll with your second solution then, I think I'm trying too hard to understand the concept of OOP and it just seemed logical to me to have each cell take care of itself. Thank you!

Comment: Check out [this book](http://www.amazon.com/Head-First-Object-Oriented-Analysis-Design/dp/0596008678). It has really simple approach to pass the ideas and somehow makes them stick.

Answer (score 2):

What about keeping a link to worldobjects in your cell:

Cell.py

```
#from World import worldobjects #This is the problem, python does not like cross imports

class Cell:
    def __init__(self, worldobjects):
        self.lifetime = 0 #Keep track of frames spent 'alive'
        self.worldobjects = worldobjects

    def update(self):
        self.lifetime += 1 
        if self.lifetime > 30:
            self.worldobjects.append(Cell(self.worldobjects)) #Add a new cell to the world
            self.lifetime = 0 #Reset lifetime
```

World.py

```
import Cell

worldobjects = []

for i in range(10): #create  a bunch of initial cells
    worldobjects.append(Cell.Cell(worldobjects))

while True:
    for obj in worldobjects:
        obj.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I agree with @RickyA on this matter and all the other comments about the design of provided sample, I ran into similar problems with Flask and WSGI containers, which require globals (at least app object), so additional alertness regarding circular imports is required. It's nothing from outer space, but it comes as a nuisance.

Maybe the following approach will help someone with similar issues (including the very poster here). So, one possibility would be to extract globals in a separate file, which serves as an import intermediary. It cannot solve every problem in class of circular imports, but is pretty straightforward in cases where it's applicable.

Cell.py

```
import WorldObjects

class Cell:
    def __init__(self):
        self.lifetime = 0 #Keep track of frames spent 'alive'

    def update(self):

        self.lifetime += 1 
        if self.lifetime > 30:
            WorldObjects.objects.append(Cell()) #Add a new cell to the world
            self.lifetime = 0 #Reset lifetime
```

World.py

```
import Cell
import WorldObjects

for i in range(10): #create  a bunch of initial cells
    WorldObjects.objects.append(Cell.Cell())

while True:
    for obj in WorldObjects.objects:
        obj.update()
```

WorldObjects.py

```
objects = []
```